# Apache Ant {Compile javac srcdir} does not exist

Tags: java, ant

I am new to apache ant and I am currently working on an apache Ant project. I Just started out, imported the project into workspace and tried to run the build.xml. I added all the libraries that come with the original project to the build path. I am having the following problem. Please someone else wrote the code and I am supposed to improve it. The directories this is all about exist in the project directory.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\MyApp\build.xml:83: srcdir "C:\workspace\MyApp\${compile.javac.srcdir}"     does not exist!
```

The error code is referencing the following part of the build.xml file

```
<target name="compile.default" depends="init">
    <javac fork="yes" srcdir="${compile.javac.srcdir}" destdir="${compile.javac.destdir}" includes="${compile.javac.include}" excludes="${compile.javac.exclude}" classpath="${compile.javac.classpath}" debug="${compile.javac.debug}" optimize="${compile.javac.optimize}" deprecation="${compile.javac.deprecation}" verbose="${compile.javac.verbose}">
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${compile.javac.destdir}">
        <fileset dir="${compile.javac.srcdir}" includes="${compile.copy.include}" excludes="${compile.copy.exclude}"/>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="compile" depends="init,compile.default" description="Compile all java source">
</target>
<!--+++++++++++++++-->
<!-- lib target(s) -->
<!--+++++++++++++++-->
<target name="lib.default" depends="init,compile">

    <xmlbean schema="config/schemas/validate/1.0/validate.xsd" destfile="lib/glx-beans.jar" classpath="lib/xbean.jar:lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar" />

    <jar jarfile="${lib.filename}">
        <fileset dir="${lib.srcdir}"  excludes="${lib.exclude}" />
    </jar>



</target>

<target name="lib" depends="init,compile,lib.default" description="Create all Project Libraries">
</target>
```

Would you please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: where is `${compile.javac.srcdir}` defined? some property may be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${compile.javac.srcdir}` isn't defined. There are a few possibilities:

- This is defined not in the `build.xml`, but in some sort of properties file. See if you have something like `<property file="..."/>` in your build script. My recommendation is to have all properties defined in the `build.xml` file, and use a properties file to override those settings. This way, the only build file that a developer needs in the `build.xml` file and doesn't have to worry about setting up a separate `build.porperties` file.
- This is defined in the `build.xml` file under a particular task, but you forgot to say that your target where you use thisis dependent upon this task.

One of the things you can do is use the `-d` parameter when running Ant. I run the following command when running Ant with the `-d` parameter:

```
$ and -d 2>&1 | tee ant.out
```

I can then look at `ant.out` and see if somehow I didn't define that particular property. Maybe I had the wrong capitalization or misspelled the property name. For example, it's very likely I'll define the property as *copmile.javac.srcdir* because I don't know how to spell. Looking at the `-d` output can quickly point these types of errors out.

By the way, you shouldn't have all of your tasks dependent upon `init` since they're dependent upon `compile.default` anyway:

```
<target name="compile.default" depends="init">
    ....
</target>
<target name="compile" depends="compile.default">
    ....
</target>
<target name="lib" depends="compile,lib.default">
    ....
</target>
```

If I run the target `lib`, it will see `compile` is dependent upon `compile.default` which is dependent upon `init`. Thus, your build will run `init`, then `compile.default`, then `compile`, then 'lib.default`and finally`lib`.

If the init task is just setting up properties, you can do that outside of any task. Then, these properties will be setup before any task is executed. This way, they're not forgotten. If your `init` is also creating directories, you may want to move those `<mkdir/>` tasks in front of the task where that directory is used. For example, you may want to make the *destdir* uses in `javac` before the `<javac/>` task.

I find assigning default properties outside of any task, and creating directories before they are needed to simplify the `build.xml`. Plus, you're not creating a whole flock of unused directories if the user is merely compiling and not packaging the jar/war/etc.

Comment: Hey @David, I can see the following `<property file="config/project-${target.env}.properties"/> ` in the build.xml plus three different physical property files (One for DEV, one for PROD and another for TEST) I am in DEV, how can I link the property to the DEV property file?

Comment: You need to set the property `target.env` to the right property. Try `$ ant -Dtarget.env="dev"`. Make sure the casing is the same as the file name. I recommend you add `<property name="target.env" value="dev"/>` to assume that you're using the DEV environment unless you specify otherwise on the command line. You can always override it, but the build won't fail if the developer forgets to set the property.